# CMake top-level configuring sub-modules

Tags: cmake, build-system

I'm in the process of bringing CMake into an older project.  One goal is to start following good modern CMake principles - i.e. think in terms of modules.  One goal with modern CMake is for modules to be able to stand alone apart from a top-level that would create a dependency on it via `add_subdirectory`.

One thing this project does is define a platform.h file that basically all submodules include.  I assume this is an anti-pattern since it's creating a dependency in the wrong direction - i.e. lower layer libraries depend on a file in the topmost layer.

My question - if you want to tell submodules various settings to use at compile-time is there a modern CMake way to do this?  I imagine this would be similar to how the Linux kernel sets values in kconfig files that are updated throughout the source during a make config.  There it's also the top-level that is influencing submodules.

EDIT:
I know you can pass defines with the cmake build command, but it seems cumbersome if there's more than just a few.

Comment: "Modern CMake" tells to build submodules **separately** (not with `add_subdirectory`), and then use `find_package()` in the top-level project. Such a way you will have no dependencies of submodules from the top-level project. As for building similar submodules from the top-level project, I know no perfect solution. Defining `platform.h` at the top-level is possible approach.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I agree that separate projects for dependencies (creating a package then find_package() is the ultimate for decoupling, but I've not heard that is a requirement to being "modern".  I watched Mathieu Ropert's CppCon talk recently and it seems perfectly legit to be using add_subdirectory and conforming to modern CMake ideals.  His emphasis is that modern CMake is all about modularity.  You can achieve modularity whether your target is defined within the scope of a project or external to a project.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eC9-iRN2b04

Comment: Well, it is true about modularity. I meant that if you want modules to be independent from the top-level project, you need to build them sepately.